# Unity3d rotate arrow towards mouse position

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, gameobject

In unity I have an arrow sprite with pivot on the start of the arrow.

Now I need to rotate that arrow in 2d so it always points towards the mouse. 
It needs to be done with `lerp` or `slerp` so when I move mouse too fast, it doesn't jump there but it slowly slides to that position.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: It is not my first time to post a question. I made it intentionally to see different ideas. I didn't want to show mine solution so people don't do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

I just answered a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44297699/edit). For simplicity, the following code is an [example from the Unity forum](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/731922/rotate-object-to-face-mouse-2d-rotate-on-z-axis.html) that you can use to rotate an object around the z-axis.

```
Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
Vector3 dir = Input.mousePosition - pos;
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
```

[Here is the Unity3D documentation for slerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html), and [here is the documentation for lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html). It should be straight forward to modify the code to do what you want from these examples.

Answer (score 0):

It all comes down to how your arrow is setup, can you use the rotateTowards?

If so you can use [ScreenToWorldPoint](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) with rotateTowards

(ps, function is not tested since im at work :P)

```
void Update() {
    transform.rotateTowards(camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, camera.nearClipPlane));
}
```

as for the lerp function, you should be [Check here for speed variable stuff](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.RotateTowards.html)

Happy Coding.

Comment: The arrow is a sprite. It is in 0,0. Pivot is the bottom of the arrow, and it is pointing to the top. It should look like analog clock, arrow should rotate like clock hand, pointing towards mouse.I am using this, but it's not working, front face is rotating towards mouse
`float lookFactor = 0.5f;
float distance = (transform.position.z - Camera.main.transform.position.z) * lookFactor;
Vector3 position = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, distance);
position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(position);
transform.LookAt(position);`